# Look Behind Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm starting with Regex (always used from the net the ones I needed)

I need something that given the input:

```
Input: AAABBBCCC
Index: 012345678
```

The regex matches would be:

- AA from 0,1
- AA from 1,2 (even though the A from 1 is already consumed)
- BB from 3,4
- BB from 4,5 (even though the B from 4 is already consumed)
- CC from 6,7
- CC from 7,8 (even though the B from 7 is already consumed)

The regex I have now is `(A{2}|B{2}|C{2})`.
It is not my real problem, but I have different workings Regexes for the As, Bs and Cs.

I think that I should use some `look behind` operator but trying: `((A{2}|B{2}|C{2})$1)` or `(?<=(A{2}|B{2}|C{2}))` won't work.

[Here's an example](http://regexr.com?35eqb).

**Note:** My problem is in c#, if that matters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do need lookaround but I'd use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that:

```
(?=(([ABC])\2))
```

Your match results will be in `match.Groups(1)` of each `match` object.

**Explanation:**

```
(?=       # Look ahead to check that the following matches:
 (        # Match and capture in group number 1:
  (       # Match and capture in group number 2:
   [ABC]  # Any letter A, B or C
  )       # End of capturing group 2
  \2      # Now match that same letter again.
 )        # End of group 1. It now contains AA, BB or CC
)         # End of lookahead assertion
```

A simpler solution:

```
(?=(AA|BB|CC))
```

Comment: Thank Tim, I'm trying the the last solution, but cannot make it work: http://regexr.com?35eqh

Comment: Use a better regex tester :) http://regex101.com/r/yZ6jL3 (the problem may be that the matches itself are zero characters in length, which regexr doesn't visualize. Only the capturing group contains actual text). On second thought, it looks like there is a bug in regexr. It finds `(?=(AA|BB|CC))` to be invalid and `(?=(AA|BB|CC)` to be valid...

Comment: Hello tim i couldnt make it named group can you also add named group solution ?